# "TypeError: neighbors[o.source.index] is undefined" when replacing example data in D3 data visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, typeerror

I'm following this [Force-based Label Placement](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729) tutorial for D3. The example comes with randomly generated nodes and random links. I'm trying to replace the these random elements with my data. Below is the code, and I commented out the original section to add in my own data based on the information given in the original code, namely the section that gets comment out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?2.6.0"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var w = 960, h = 500;

            var labelDistance = 0;

            var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

            var nodes = [];
            var labelAnchors = [];
            var labelAnchorLinks = [];
            var links = [];

            // for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            //  var node = {
            //      label : "node " + i
            //  };
            //  nodes.push(node);
            //  labelAnchors.push({
            //      node : node
            //  });
            //  labelAnchors.push({
            //      node : node
            //  });
            // };

            // for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            //  for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            //      if(Math.random() > .95)
            //          links.push({
            //              source : i,
            //              target : j,
            //              weight : Math.random()
            //          });
            //  }
            //  labelAnchorLinks.push({
            //      source : i * 2,
            //      target : i * 2 + 1,
            //      weight : 1
            //  });
            // };


            // my own code to insert data starts here. 
            nodes = [
                        {label : "A"},
                        {label : "B"},
                        {label : "C"}
                    ];

            labelAnchors = [
                        {node : "A"},
                        {node : "B"},
                        {node : "C"}
            ];

            links = [
                        {source : "A", target : "B", weight: 10},
                        {source : "B", target : "C", weight: 1},
                        {source : "C", target : "A", weight: 5}
            ];

            labelAnchorLinks = [
                        {source : "A", target : "B", weight: 10},
                        {source : "B", target : "C", weight: 1},
                        {source : "C", target : "A", weight:5}
            ];
            // my own code to insert data ends here. 

            var force = d3.layout.force().size([w, h]).nodes(nodes).links(links).gravity(1).linkDistance(50).charge(-3000).linkStrength(function(x) {
                return x.weight * 10
            });


            force.start();

            var force2 = d3.layout.force().nodes(labelAnchors).links(labelAnchorLinks).gravity(0).linkDistance(0).linkStrength(8).charge(-100).size([w, h]);
            force2.start();

            var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(links).enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "link").style("stroke", "#CCC");

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(force.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "node");
            node.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 5).style("fill", "#555").style("stroke", "#FFF").style("stroke-width", 3);
            node.call(force.drag);

            // bind data to links
            var anchorLink = vis.selectAll("line.anchorLink").data(labelAnchorLinks)//.enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "anchorLink").style("stroke", "#999");

            // bind data and text to circles
            var anchorNode = vis.selectAll("g.anchorNode").data(force2.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "anchorNode");
            anchorNode.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 0).style("fill", "#FFF");
            anchorNode.append("svg:text").text(function(d, i) {
                return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.label
            }).style("fill", "#555").style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12);

            var updateLink = function() {
                this.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            }

            var updateNode = function() {
                this.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

            }

            force.on("tick", function() {

                force2.start();

                node.call(updateNode);

                anchorNode.each(function(d, i) {
                    if(i % 2 == 0) {
                        d.x = d.node.x;
                        d.y = d.node.y;
                    } else {
                        var b = this.childNodes[1].getBBox();

                        var diffX = d.x - d.node.x;
                        var diffY = d.y - d.node.y;

                        var dist = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

                        var shiftX = b.width * (diffX - dist) / (dist * 2);
                        shiftX = Math.max(-b.width, Math.min(0, shiftX));
                        var shiftY = 5;
                        this.childNodes[1].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + shiftX + "," + shiftY + ")");
                    }
                });


                anchorNode.call(updateNode);

                link.call(updateLink);
                anchorLink.call(updateLink);

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the error I'm getting is `TypeError: neighbors[o.source.index] is undefined`...what is wrong?

Comment: `neighbors[o.source.index]` doesn't appear to be in any of the code you posted..? Post the section of code that the error occurs on?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the error is in d3.v2.js that you can find here: https://gist.github.com/mscook/b21a1877cba76565937a. However, I think it's my own fault that causes this error for some reason, as if you just leave the sample code as it is, without inserting my own data, it works perfectly.

Comment: In your last question on a force you used d3v4, out of curiosity, why the switch to v2? It's much harder to debug v2 as it doesn't have the same level of documentation.

Comment: There are a couple issues from what I can see, the original uses numerical indexes rather than strings to mark links (source/target) as there is no method to set id in v2 from what I can see (ultimate source of the error message). But there are also some other departures from the example (for example anchor modes are pushed twice as {node:node} in the anchor node array, you are using a plain array of nodes without duplicating each node in a new object.

Comment: @AndrewReid I noticed the version differences. I'm just trying to find the  most appropriate form. I'm looking for certain characteristics and aesthetics for a project. Although this one looks very similar from the one in my last question, it is more appropriate for my purpose, as I don't want overlapping at all and this one has some great details such as labels adjusted to left and right based on its location. Overall it saves more work/trouble for me, as I'm new to D3.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen newer examples that use force layouts to place labels on force layout graphs (and of course can't find them quickly now), but here's a demo using your data modified to match the form of the example: http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/137fffb14cf52e5d3f16c554ada81c67 . I edited the weights to be between 0 and 1 for the regular lengths for this though.

Comment: @AndrewReid this is perfect. do you want to add this as answer, so I can adopt it? thanks for helping me twice today. also just curious: why is labelAnchors get pushed twice though?

Comment: I believe this is because the anchors are used in both forces, and only half of the anchors make it into each force, for example, in creating the nodes, we see a line filtering every second element: `if(i % 2 == 0) {`

Comment: I am certain I have seen more recent examples of this arrangement, but am drawing blanks in trying to find one. Might have to mock one up in the near future, a newer version of d4 should allow a cleaner and clearer implementation and give the flexibility to incorporate other examples better.

Comment: @AndrewReid I saw this: http://jsfiddle.net/P54AS/46/, which uses v3. Very similar, but the v2 example does 95% of what I want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't adopting the examples data structure, and consequently, the graph breaks.

Let's take a look piece by piece.

First, the original node generator:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  var node = {
    label : "node " + i
  };
  nodes.push(node);
  labelAnchors.push({
    node : node
  });
  labelAnchors.push({
    node : node
  });
};
```

Here you are partially ok, the nodes array is fine, but the `labelAnchor`is where you first deviate from the example:

```
labelAnchors = [
  {node : "A"},
  {node : "B"},
  {node : "C"}
 ];
```

This doesn't duplicate the nodes and it doesn't place the nodes in newer objects: `{node:node}`. You can fix this with:

```
var labelAnchors = [];
nodes.forEach(function(n) {
   labelAnchors.push({node:n},{node:n});
})
```

Now let's look back at how the links are generated in the original:

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if(Math.random() > .95)
      links.push({
        source : i,
        target : j,
        weight : Math.random()
      });
    }
    labelAnchorLinks.push({
      source : i * 2,
      target : i * 2 + 1,
      weight : 1
     });
    };
```

The first issue in your code is that you assign strings as node ids, this results in a failure of the link to access the nodes it is connected to. In d3v2 we need to use the index of the target node (in d3v3/4/5 we can set an id property of the node to avoid the need to keep track of indexes).

To fix this for the main links we can use:

```
links = [
  {source : 0, target : 1, weight: Math.random()},
  {source : 1, target : 2, weight: Math.random()},
  {source : 2, target : 0, weight: Math.random()}
];
```

Lastly, we can see that the example uses some manipulation to the indexes to link anchor and label. You've originally used strings, but we need to use these modified indexes. Source will be i*2 and target will be i*2+1:

```
labelAnchorLinks = [
  {source : 0*2, target : 0*2+1, weight: 1},
  {source : 1*2, target : 1*2+1, weight: 1},
  {source : 2*2, target : 2*2+1, weight: 1}
];
```

*Or, as the label anchor links must link anchor node with the proper label node, we can set this autmatically:*

```
var labelAnchorLinks = [];
nodes.forEach(function(d,i) {
  var link = {};
  link.source = i * 2;
  link.target = i * 2 + 1;
  link.weight = 1;
  labelAnchorLinks.push(link);
})
```

Given all that, we should be able get a functioning graph: http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/137fffb14cf52e5d3f16c554ada81c67

Comment: For some reason, if all the nodes are connected to their next nodes and the last nodes connect to the first node, this works fine (A -> B -> C -> D ->E -> F -> A). If I add more random source/target connection this breaks the graph, and the labels are floating randomly. For example, in this: jsfiddle.net/8xgd4smy/7.

Comment: As each node is duplicated in the nodes array, the label-anchor links must link the paired nodes, hence source and target being: `i * 2`, `i * 2 + 1` (label node and anchor node). You're mixing nodes like: `i*2`,`j*2+1`, breaking the link. These don't need to be set manually, you can set them automatically as they aren't discretionary, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcrq9zz1/1/).

Comment: @practicemakesperfect Also, sorry, missed that I mixed up the anchor-label links as well in the answer, I've updated it to reflect these changes.